# split string into array and add the delimiter to the array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

i have an String and i need to split this String to array 
My String is for example "-2x+3"

i split it with this code

```
public static String[] splitAnswer(String answerInput){
        answerInput = answerInput.trim();
        String[] token = answerInput.split("[\\+\\-\\*\\\\\\/]");
        return token;
    }
```

but i need the minus sign with 2x i.e. (-2x) and my array output  will be `{"-2x","3"}`
the important thing i need the minus with the number after

Comment: What is the expected output from the input  "-2x+3"?

Comment: my  purpose to check the answer of student if it's right or not 

for example if the answer is -2x+3 and the student answer +3-2x 
the answer must be correct that what i search to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regex:

```
String[] token = answerInput.split("[+*/]|(?=-)")
```

So, this splits on all the operators, except `-`. For `-` operator, it splits on empty string before the `-` operator. BTW, you don't need to escape anything inside the character class.

For `-2x + 3`, the split positions are:

```
|-2x+3   ( `|` is empty space)
^   ^
```